# How long does a posted review last on the Android store?

Tags: google-play-store

I have given reviews before and then came back some time later and noticed they were gone.

What is the duration that the android store displays my reviews?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions regarding the Android Market (now Google Play Store) that are about the internal workings of the store and aren't about interacting with the Store app via your Android device aren't really on-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to leave a review again from the same account, does it let you?  Does it show the previous review, or act like nothing has been input before?

Reviews shouldn't age off (unless they're removed for profanity or other reasons), but some developers have noted that ratings suddenly disappeared from their app.  Maybe it was a one-time bug.